# Is an empty while loop considered bad practice?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I am to download data from the server, with a maximum of 3 attempts if the download fails.

```
public class DownloadFile {

    private boolean isSuccessful;

    public DownloadFile() {
        int attempt = 0;

        while(!isSuccessful && (attempt++ < 3)) {
            DownloadFileThread.start();
            while (DownloadFileThread.isAlive());
        }
    }

    private Thread DownloadFileThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // download file from server

                isSuccessful = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isSuccessful = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see in the above example, I have an empty `while` loop in (what would be) line 10 to force guarantee `isSuccessful` is assignment a value based on the outcome of the `DownloadFileThread` before checking the condition in the `while` loop again.

Is it considered *bad practice* to do such a thing? Is there *better* approach or a *correct way* to do this?

While the above code does produce a valid result, I am not exactly proud of the code I have written...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in this case it is a bad practice, because Java offers better mechanisms to wait for completion of a thread: [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()), or consider using more modern features like [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) or an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) that allows you to wait for a task to complete.

Using an empty loop to wait will consume a lot of CPU power unnecessarily, which might mean other tasks on your system will perform slower than they could otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, but in this case this is a busy wait which is bad practice especially in multi-threaded programs. It keeps the CPU busy and in your case interferes with DownloadFileThread.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the while loop will execute permanently stealing process time from other things, maybe also from your download thread.
If you simply want to wait until your download is done, why don´t you use Thread.join() ?
It´s blocking, meaning that you won´t be able to execute anything in your main-thread until the DownloadThread is done but your while loop does this as well in this case and use more system resources on top.